# I keep on getting logged out after X minutes inactivity on Windows 10 Professional

Tags: windows, lock-screen

My dashboard PC that running Windows 10 Professional keep log-out after several minutes of inactivity. I have done the following:

- Disable Screen Saver
- Power Setting set all to never
- Enable AutoLogon
- Set local user (active users) to ADMIN no password
- Change Registry HKLM\Software\Policies\Windows\Microsoft\NoLockScreen
- Change Registry `HKLM\Systems\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSetting\238xxx\7bcxxx\attributesset` to `2`
- Local Policies change`-Computer Configuration\administrative\Control Panel\Personalize\` "do not display lock screen" to enable

None the above works.

Comment: Use a third-party tool such as Don't Sleep, https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/DontSleep .

Comment: Open an Adimin Command Prompt and run both DISM and SFC and restart, test.   

dism.exe  /online  /cleanurp-image /restorehealth 

SFC /SCANNOW

Comment: This seems, not working